# How to display random related portfolio items using CSS?

Tags: php, wordpress

below the single portfolio items on my website I have a function to show three related portfolio projects (an example: http://gorillastichting.nl/wordpress/portfolio/bescherming/ ). However it always displays the same projects (first three in my portfolio folder). I am not sure how I can change this in the code. Therefore my question here. The code:

```
        <h2 class="h3border"><?php _e('Gerelateerd <span>project</span>','pmc-themes'); ?></h2>
        <div class="titleborder"></div>     
        <div id="portitems4">
            <?php pmc_portfolio('port3',3,'port',3,'','false','','','','homePort',0,'related') ?>   

        </div>
```

Is there any way to change it to show three random portfolio items from the same category?
Thanks in advance,
Yannick

Comment: This is something you would do with wordpress either in the CMS itself as a setting or by making changes to the php code rendering your projects, this has nothing to do with CSS (yet) ;)

Comment: You should take a look at the pmc_portfolio function. I guess there is one param for sorting or randomness inside.